# How to fix broken TFS working folder

Tags: tfs

I don't know how, but TFS is claiming files in the same workspace folder are mapped to different local directories. The TFS client is showing me a working dir but some files are mapped to a sub-dir when I do compare/check-in operations.

I have tried to remove and reinstate the workfolder mappings but it hasn't helped.

Possibly files checked out for edit before a workfolder is remapped are to blame?

Comment: The error that I've seen is multiple workspaces containing the same folder. Do you have other workspaces? And which version of TFS/Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: 2010. I do have another workspace but that is mapping to a totally different location, not either of the dirs in question here.

Comment: Try running `tf workspaces /computer:{name}` from a Visual Studio command prompt to see whether there's one you're missing...